# Angular Material: Disable a matInput field using a directive

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I have the following directive which will disable in input if the user does not have the correct permissions. It works as expected with a regular `<input type="text">` input, however it does not work with the `matInput` directive. How can make a directive which will disable a `matInput` field?

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[hasPermission]'
  })
  export class HasPermissionDirective {

    @Input('hasPermission') permission: string
  
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, public auth: AuthService, private _overlay: Overlay ) { 
        
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if ( ! this.auth.can(this.permission) ) this.disable()
    }
  
    private disable() {
        this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true
    }
  
}
```

This works:

```html
<input type="text" hasPermission="module:permission-name">
```

This does not work:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput hasPermission="module:permission-name">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ngAfterViewInit`

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[hasPermission]'
  })
  export class HasPermissionDirective {

    @Input('hasPermission') permission: string
  
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, public auth: AuthService, private _overlay: Overlay ) { 
        
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if ( ! this.auth.can(this.permission) ) this.disable()
    }
  
    private disable() {
        this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true
    }
  
}
```